# How i can check that dynamic threads are end

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have array of imageurl, dowload by DownloadFromUrl function, calling from myfunction, I use thread, I don't know how much image url is there, for every image download seperate thread created, I want to start an activity after all of these thread end.

how could I get all of these thread, thread sleep longer can't work its not a good procedure. also I can't count to end of thread by a static variable count because sometimes image fail to download or url broken, or connection not time out,

I am little lost now, what whould be the procedute to figure out that these all thread ended?

```
public void DownloadFromUrl(String DownloadUrl, String fileName) {

               try {
                       File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();               

                       File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/"+Imageurl.facebookpage);
                   if(dir.exists()==false) {
                        dir.mkdirs();
                   }

                   URL url = new URL(DownloadUrl); //you can write here any link
                   File file = new File(dir, fileName);



                   /* Open a connection to that URL. */
                   URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

                   /*
                    * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
                    */
                   InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                   BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

                   /*
                    * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
                    */
                   ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(5000);
                   int current = 0;
                   while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                      baf.append((byte) current);
                   }


                   /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
                   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                   fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
                   fos.flush();
                   fos.close();
                   LoginActivity.statsofdownload++;

                   Log.d("DownloadManager","file://"+file.getAbsolutePath());

           } catch (IOException e) {
               Imageurl.pagestat="space";
               Log.d("DownloadManager", "Error: " + e);
           }

        }




myfunction()
{
 for(String string : Imageurl.output) {
                            imagea++;
                        final   int ind =imagea;
                        final String ss=string;
                        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                      DownloadFromUrl(ss,"IMAGE"+ind+".jpeg");
                                      File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();         




                                   Imageurl.newyearsvalues.add("file://"+root.getAbsolutePath() + "/"+Imageurl.facebookpage+ "/"+"IMAGE"+ind+".jpeg");

                              }
                                }).start();


                    }

//// now need to call an activity but how I will know that these thread all end
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***ALTERNATIVE 1**: Use `ExecutorService` with `shutdown()` and `awaitTermination()`:*

```
ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfParallelThreads);
while(...) {
  taskExecutor.execute(new downloadImage());
}
taskExecutor.shutdown();
try {
  taskExecutor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  ...
}
```

Basically, what `shutdown()` does is that it stops `ExecutorService` from accepting any more thread request.
`awaitTermination()` awaits until `ExecutorService` has finished executing all threads.

***ALTERNATIVE 2:** Use `CountDownLatch`:*

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(totalNumberOfImageDownloadTasks);
ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfParallelThreads);
while(...) {
  taskExecutor.execute(new downloadImage());
}

try {
  latch.await();
} catch (InterruptedException E) {
   // handle
}
```

and within you imageDowloader() function add line:

```
latch.countDown();
```

This will increment latch's value by 1 on every execution.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating a new thread per runnable, you may want to use a single [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)'s `execute` method so that you can reuse threads once they complete their work.

As for determining when your threads have finished, use a static [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) to track successful completions, and another static ConcurrentLinkedQueue to track unsuccessful completions that may need to be retried.  Then in your run() method you would include the code

```
public void run() {
    try {
        ...
        successfulCompletionQueue.offer(this);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        unsuccessfulCompletionQueue.offer(this);
    }
}
```

where `this` is whatever logging information is relevant to the task at hand.

Answer (score 1):

To identify the finishing, use `asynctask`, `onPostExceute()` method you can be sure all images are downloaded, if you need progressing download to use the images while download you can also check out the progress.

as `onPostExecute()` method runs in ui thread, there should not be any problem now.

But remember same `asynctask` can't be executed multiple times. In that case you got 2 choices:

1. download all images in one `asynctastask` and update activity from its `onPostExecute()`
2. execute seperate `asynctask` for each download. and use each `onPostExecute()` to update activity.

Comment: Do i call forloop in asynctask? or asynck task will call in forllop for every download?

Comment: just calling your myfunction() onetime from asynctask from doInBackground() should be good.